# Undefined offset NOTICE when extracting array

Tags: php, arrays

When I run this code, it works, but it gives me NOTICE 'Undefined offset 1'. Can someone tell me how can I fix this? $this->_data is a multidimensional array.

```
foreach ($this->_data as $key => $values) {
    $this->_param[] = explode(",", $values[1]);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to output the content of `$this->_data` to see if there is $values[1]?

Comment: yes, it's all working fine but still gives me that notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there is any data in `$values[1]`

Use this:

```
foreach ($this->_data as $key => $values) {
    if (isset($values[1]){
       $this->_param[] = explode(",", $values[1]);
    }
}
```